# JS, making a symbol into a parameter

Tags: javascript

So, I am trying to make following js into a function:

```
SOMETHING.html(parseInt(SOMETHING.html()) + 1);

function RH_COUNT(a,b){
    return a.html(parseInt(a.html()) b 1);  
};
```

how do I make a symbol (plus sign "+") into a function parameter?

Comment: use `parseInt(a.html(),10)` to avoid a base 8 calculation in IE9.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add 1 or -1 as a param, and then add the two, with one multiplied by the param. Like so:

```
function RH_COUNT(a,b){
    return a.html(parseInt(a.html()) + 1 * b);  
};

RH_COUNT( <param>, 1 );
RH_COUNT( <param>, -1 );
```

As you wish, you can also make a variable out of those numbers, like so:

```
var PLUS = 1, MINUS = -1;

function RH_COUNT(a,b){
    return a.html(parseInt(a.html()) + 1 * b);  
};

RH_COUNT( <param>, PLUS );
RH_COUNT( <param>, MINUS );
```

Comment: That's a clever way of doing it! Thanks for the help! =)

Comment: Oh, and if you're always adding or subtracting 1, then just do "+ b". But you figured that out yourself I guess :-)

Answer (score 2):

You must define a plus function:

```
function plus(x, y)
{
    return x + y;
}
```

Inside RH_COUNT you use it like this:

```
function RH_COUNT(a, b)
{
    return a.html( b(parseInt(a.html()), 1) );
    //             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ this is the plus() invocation
}
```

Now you can pass it to the RH_COUNT function:

```
RH_COUNT(SOMETHING, plus);
```

In ES6 (Harmony) you can leverage the arrow syntax for a one-liner invocation without the need to define the plus function:

```
RH_COUNT(SOMETHING, (x, y) => x + y );
//                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ this is the "plus" lambda
```

Comment: Ah, i see. I would not have known this way. Thanks for the help! =)